# SSL support on nginx, Godaddy SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, nginx, certificate

Following Godaddy instructions, I have generated a private key and the corresponding CSR:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout mydomain.key -out mydomain.csr
```

Then, I uploaded *mydomain.csr* to Godaddy, getting a ZIP file containing the SSL and intermediate certificates, which I concatenated to have a single CRT file:

```
cat mysslcert.crt intermediate.crt >> mydomain.crt
```

Using the official NGINX image from the docker hub, the configuration is the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    keepalive_timeout 10m;
    root /var/www;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/mydomain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/mydomain.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on; ...
```

The files are accessible (checked with wrong paths). The error I'm getting is the following:

```
    SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/etc/ssl/mydomain.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)
```

The comparison of the MD5 tells me they're different, but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: try using `mysslcert.crt` directly and see if it that works?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @TarunLalwani, the problem was that the certificate that I can download from Godaddy takes time to be refreshed when a new CSR is uploaded. The solution is that I had to wait for the actual email indicating that my certificate is ready to be downloaded.